# Chive and Laravel Routing

Tags: laravel-routing

i tried to extract chive in the public folder of laravel. now i get this error
Ajax request failed after i login to chive.

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception     \\NotFoundHttpException","message":"","file":"\/var\/www\/archiver\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/RouteCollection.php","line":148}}
```

please help me to properly install chive.

Comment: there is no code to install chive. what do you mean? i just extracted it to the public directory. unfortunately after i log in to chive i get that error.

Comment: do you know how to make laravel routes ignore a folder? it's in public/chive. i think that might fix the problem. like in the .htaccess of chive or anything. i'm noob so i'm not really sure